# Set style.display="none" to jquery hide()

Tags: jquery, css

I have many `.style.display="none"` like below,it not work for Firefox so I want to change it to something like `$("#inp_0151").hide();` ,but there are so many this.

Is there a faster way to change it?

I will put it in `$(document).ready`.
If the last words are `.style.display="none"` I will change it to `.hide()`
If the last words are `.style.display="block"` I will change it to `.show()`

```
document.getElementById("inp_131").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("avc").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("qwe").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("89").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("135").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("inp").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("io").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("inp_171").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("inp_172").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("inp_173").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("inp_174").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("inp_175").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("inp_01527").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("inp_176").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("inp_177").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: var $parents = $(...).parents().filter(function() {
                  return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
               });

Comment: I found this is good

Comment: And it's not about .style.display don't work ,it's because I have a ajax working in offline,so when the firefox catch the offline ajax then error happen,not move forward to next function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function on your code editor. `Find` and `Replace`
You put the `.style.display = "none"` on Find and `.hide();` to replace. And don't be too lazy on other.

Answer (score 0):

You can group toghether the name of selector like so :

```
$("#inp_131, #avc,....").hide();
```

Comment: This way I still need to type each id of them,because I have hundred of id.

Comment: Yes of course you should, unless you put all of these selectors name into array and loop all of them to either show or hide

Comment: Can I directly set  .style.display attribute=="none" = hide() and  .style.display attribute=="block"  = show() ?

Comment: Yes you can but make sure the selector is correct. Is the data dynamically created? And if so, is it the element was created under same main container or parent container?

Comment: How can I do not select any ,just change the js file of  document.getElementById("inp_015").style.display="none"; to $("inp_015").hide()?  Because some of them are none some of them are block

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class name t your elements then call it by classname.

document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenelements").style.display = "none";

Comment: .style.display  not work for firefox so I chenge it to hide()

Comment: Hi sorry, can you try this instead.document.getElementById("io").css({"display":none});